# Parallel DB/WS Calls

Tags: java

I am building a set of web services with the intent to aggregate similar data sets across multiple backends (through db calls and service calls).  Some of the queries could take more than a couple of seconds to run, and if I stack these requests sequentially, there is a chance the total run time would be outside of the desired response time.

I am hoping to make the calls in parallel, collect all results and then aggregate.  What is the best approach to tackling this?

The services will be deployed to Websphere 6.1 (so java 5, j2ee 1.4).

Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into the [java.util.concurrent](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) API.  In particular, you can create a thread [Executor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html), pass in [Callable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html)s, and get back [Future](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html)s, that will be run asynchronously.

Your code will look something like this:

```
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

Future<ReplyA> raFuture = exec.submit(new Callable<ReplyA>() {
  public ReplyA call() {
    // call remote service here.
    return new ReplyA(...);
  }});

Future<ReplyB> rbFuture = exec.submit(new Callable<ReplyB>() {
  public ReplyB call() {
    // call remote service here.
    return new ReplyB(...);
  }});

ReplyA replyA = raFuture.get();
ReplyB replyB = rbFuture.get();

exec.shutdown();
```

You can also use the timeout versions of get() so you can do something reasonable if the responses are taking too long.  If you decide to take this path, you would probably be better served with the ExecutorService's invokeAll method, so the timeout will apply to all of the Callables as a group:

```
Callable<Reply> taskA = new Callable<ReplyA>() { ... };
Callable<Reply> taskB = new Callable<ReplyB>() { ... };

List<Callable<Reply>> tasks = Arrays.asList(taskA, taskB);
List<Future<Reply>> futures = exec.invokeAll(tasks, 20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

for(Future<Reply> future: futures) {
  if(replyFuture.isCancelled()) {
    // deal with it
  } else {
    Reply reply = future.get();
    // do something with the reply.
  }
}
```

Comment: If the OP is going to implement the services as EJB methods, wouldn't this approach cause a problem? According to the specs, EJBs are not to create threads of their own (how a container deals with that is another issue... if a container deals with it at all.)

Comment: i wasn't planning on creating these as EJBs.  I was planning on creating a series of value objects that would exposed through web services.

Comment: this solution lead me to WorkManager apis, which I will be using.  With them, I can include in an EJB if I desire to use EJBs.

Answer (score 0):

Start daemon threads, let them do the job, join() them all, aggregate.

Another possible way is to place the queries into a Queue, and let MDBs handle one request at a time. Aggregation is a bit more confusing though -- have to get results from another queue, and accumulate them between replies, and handle the errors... uh, common, just do the threads! :)

```
RequestAThread rath = new RequestAThread(dataForRequestA);
RequestBThread rbth = new RequestBThread(dataForRequestB);

...

rath.start();
rbth.start();

...

rath.join();
ReplyA ra = rath.getReply();

rbth.join();
ReplyB rb = rbth.getReply();

Result r = aggregate(ra,rb);
```

Error handling by taste.

Comment: any concern about threads in a application container?  i believe i read somewhere that this direction was less than desirable (app server isn't managing them).

Comment: Indeed, according to the EE specs, EJBs and other managed entities are not supposed to create threads on their own.

Comment: and in the event i choose to use EJBs, the only option would be MDB?  Also, have you come across any examples online for handling this with EJBs?  I'd like to further explore this.